# from strace output to I/O pattern simulator

Tags: nfs, strace

I have a commercial (closed-source) app that is causing some I/O related problems when run over nfs. Using strace I see all the file accesses in the strace output.

I would like to use that strace output and create a tool that simulates the same access pattern so that I have a reproducer that does not require a software license or other requisites.

Is there a tool to create a reproducer from strace output? Any other suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer myself. I found two approaches/solutions to this:

1. strace almost spits out c code. With a bit of filtering and some glue code you can generate a C source that simulates the access pattern. If timing is important this can also be accomplished when using strace -ttt or -r output and adding sleeps to the code.
2. there's this project: https://github.com/SNIA/reanimator-strace which offers a modifed strace that stores all traces in to a database and can replay that database using https://github.com/SNIA/reanimator-replayer. However, so far I failed to make this compile on RHEL7